# map lambda x,y with a constant x

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

What would be an elegant way to `map` a two parameter `lambda` function to a list of values where the first parameter is constant and the second is taken from a `list`?

**Example:**

```
lambda x,y: x+y
x='a'
y=['2','4','8','16']
```

expected result:

```
['a2','a4','a8','a16']
```

Notes:

- This is just an example, the actual lambda function is more complicated
- Assume I can't use list comprehension

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `itertools.starmap`

```
a = itertools.starmap(lambda x,y: x+y, zip(itertools.repeat(x), y))
a = list(a)
```

and you get your desired output.

BTW, both `itertools.imap` and Python3's `map` will accept the following:

```
itertools.imap(lambda x,y: x+y, itertools.repeat(x), y)
```

The default Python2's `map` will not stop at the end of `y` and will insert `None`s...

---

But a comprehension is **much** better

```
[x + num for num in y]
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting pythonic list comprehension instead of that gross ol' map function (= -- although I just noticed the asker states "assume I can't use list comprehension"

Answer (score 11):

Also you could use closure for this

```
x='a'
f = lambda y: x+y
map(f, ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
>>> ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
```

Answer (score 10):

**Python 2.x**

```
from itertools import repeat

map(lambda (x, y): x + y, zip(repeat(x), y))
```

**Python 3.x**

```
map(lambda xy: ''.join(xy), zip(repeat(x), y))
```

Comment: @JBernardo, did they take 'unpacking in signature' away?  I seem to remember something along those lines.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested `starmap` on my answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
def prependConstant(x, y):
  return map(lambda yel: x + yel, y)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
['a' + x for x in y]
```

or if you really need a callable:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x + y

[f('a', x) for x in y]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use lambda?

```
>>> x='a'
>>> y=['2','4','8','16']
>>> map(x.__add__, y)
['a2', 'a4', 'a8', 'a16']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

> BTW, both itertools.imap and Python3's map will accept the following:
>
> itertools.imap(lambda x,y: x+y, itertools.repeat(x), y)
> The default Python2's map will not stop at the end of y and will insert Nones...

I just wanted to add on to this answer that in python 2.x you can do something like

```
map(lambda x,y: x+y, itertools.repeat(x, len(y)))
```

to get itertools to stop iterating.